# Is it possible to add custom serialisation to Rebus FakeBus to support polymorphic types using .NET 6.0 or lower?

Tags: rebus

I have upgraded the version of Rebus.6.7.0 to 7.2.0 and Rebus.TestHelpers.7.2.0 to 8.0.0 and a unit test that was previously passing is now failing due to a desterilisation change.

The unit test creates a SagaFixture and delivers an event message `SomethingFailedEvent` which contains a property of type `Exception`. The exception type assigned is `typeof(ArgumentException)` with a custom message "Invalid Argument".

Within the Saga; the `SomethingFailedEvent` message handler publishes a new event message `FailedResponse` with a string property `ErrorMessage` set to the incoming event messages `Exception.Message` property.

The test then asserts that a `FailedResponse` message was published with a `ErrorMessage` property set to the `SomethingFailedEvent` Exception's message.

The test failure is caused by the fact that System.Text.Json is used for deserialisation which doesn't support polymorphic types (pre .NET 7.0). So when the `SomethingFailedEvent` message is delivered to the Saga the Exception type is desearlised to System.Exception and not the intended type `ArgumentException` and thus the `Exception.Message` property is 'Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.' which causes the assert to fail.

Code snippets below create a representation of the above scenario.

```
/// Event Types
public class SomethingFailedEvent
{
    public Exception Exception { get; set; }
}

public class FailedResponse
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

/// SagaFixture Event Handler
public async Task Handle(SomethingFailedEvent message)
{
    var failedEvent = new FailedResponse
    {
        ErrorMessage = message.Exception.Message
    };

    await Bus.Publish(failedEvent);
}
```

Unit Test Code Snippet

```
[Test]
public void FailureEventReceivedCanPublishFailedMessageWithExceptionDetails()
{
    var bus = new FakeBus();
    var logger = new NullLogger<MockSaga>();
    var sagaFixture = SagaFixture.For(
        () => new MockSaga(logger, bus);

    var startSagaEvent = new MockSagaRequested();
    sagaFixture.Deliver(startSagaEvent);

    var argumentException = new ArgumentException("Invalid Argument");
    var somethingFailedEvent = new SomethingFailedEvent()
    {
        Exception = argumentException
    };

    sagaFixture.Deliver(failedEvent);

    var failedEventMessage = bus.Events.OfType<MessagePublished<FailedResponse>>().Single();
    failedEventMessage.EventMessage.ErrorMessage.Should().Contain("Invalid Argument");
}
```

Is it possible to support creating the `FakeBus` and setting the serialisation to be Newtonsoft.Json similarly to when configuring Rebus.

```
.Serialization(s => s.UseNewtonsoftJson(
    new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    }))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'll simply have to configure the saga fixture's message serializer, which can be done like this:

```cs
static RebusConfigurer GetConfigurer() => Configure
    .With(new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
    .Serialization(s => s.UseNewtonsoftJson());

using var fixture = SagaFixture.For<SomeSaga>(GetConfigurer);

fixture.Deliver(new SomeMessageWithLoop());
```

You can see the test fixture for the feature here: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.TestHelpers/blob/master/Rebus.TestHelpers.Tests/TestSagaFixture_CustomMessageSerializer.cs

Comment: There doesn’t appear to be an appropriate overload taking a Func<SomeSaga> sagaHandlerFactory and optionally Func<RebusConfigurer> configurerFactory to support instantiating Sagas with more than the default constructor.

Comment: Ah sorry, that was unclear – when using the saga fixture setup method that lets you pass a `RebusConfigurer` to it, you'll need to instantiate `BuiltinHandlerActivator` and register message handlers on it before passing it to the saga fixture factory method, e.g. by using `activator.Register(() => new MySaga());`